# How to show Material Icons in HTML2Canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html2canvas

I'm using HTML2Canvas (https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas) to render then save a div as a PNG. It all works perfectly fine, except that the Material Icons in that div are missing. Any tips? (I am a Javascript newbie)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, just stumbled across a working solution - used the "IE9 or below" code

E.g.

```
 <i class="material-icons">&#xE839;</i>
```

Instead of

```
<i class="material-icons">star_half</i>
```

https://material.io/icons/